# Объявление функций

Tags: delphi

Чем отличается объявление функций в `private` от объявления функций после `implementation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если функция объявлена в private, то это не просто функция, а метод класса. И разделе implementation все равно придется писать ее реализацию (если только она не абстрактная). Эта функция (метод) принадлежит классу и только объекты этого класса могут вызывать ее. (на самом деле там чуточку не так, в делфи свое видение приватных методов).
А вот если функция объявлена в разделе implementation, то она может вызываться только в этом модуле и только теми функциями, которые объявлены "ниже её". А вот с других модулей напрямую - никак.
Поэтому, самое первое различие - **идеологическое**. То есть, это разные концепции.
Почему же есть и то и другое? Просто когда то раньше, когда в языке pascal не было ООП, то можно было только объявлять функции и процедуры. А когда появились классы, решили не отказываться от старого багажа.

Зайдем с другой стороны - с некоторой натяжкой можно считать, что приватный метод равносилен функции/процедуре, объявленной в разделе implementation, которой есть один дополнительный параметр(он первый в списке), который указывает на объект, который вызывает этот "метод", имеет имя self и тип идентичный типу объекта. Со стороны компилятора это почти так и выглядит (он только контролирует, что бы вызывали как положено, обрабатывает виртуальные методы...)

Comment: огромное спасибо за ответ!!!

Answer (score 2):

У них сходное назначение.

`Private` - это ограничитель области видимости из объектно-ориентированного мира. При помощи него, вы можете обозначить, какие поля и методы класса будут доступны только внутри него самого.

`Implementation` может выполнять ту же функцию, даже без использования классов (в рамках парадигмы процедурного программирования). Все что входит в секцию `implementation` и не объявлено в секции `interface` не будет доступно из других модулей. Это могут быть и функции, и классы, и переменные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли какие нибудь отличия? Если есть, то какие. Просто из того, что объявленные в private функции так же не доступны из другого класса как и при прописывании их после implementation, следует то, что private вообще не нужен (или не важен).  
 

Comment: `Private` вы используете при определении класса. Сам класс при этом может находиться в секции `interface`.

Comment: Собственно @KoVadim про то и говорит.